# What do I do to complete find the bitizen mission

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What are you supposed to do in the "find the bitizen(s)"? All the emperor says is "tipping is acceptable.  find the bitizen(s)."

Answer (score 3):

To complete the Emperor's mission, you'll need to wait until you're given the task to find a particular bitizen. You'll know it's a "find a bitizen" task as there will be an icon of a person on a blue background that will show in the bottom left corner (you will probably have completed a few of these already). They are randomly generated, so it may take some time. Clicking it will tell you who you're looking for, then you need to just scan all your levels to find the person in question, and clicking on them will complete it. After that, you should be able to get your reward from the Emperor.

Comment: This is a mission from the emperor, not an icon in the bottom left

Comment: @bdukes I'm aware. The mission from the emperor gives you some credit for completing one of these find a bitizen missions. These missions pop up randomly, and you are awarded one buck for it.